# ASP.NET/IIS: How can I serve TCP connections using a custom protocol (i.e. without WCF)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, tcp, tcplistener

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that needs to administer remote devices.  These remote devices speak a custom protocol over TCP on a non-standard port.  To communicate with these devices, I use a TcpListener and maintain connections with all of them.  When an administration request comes through the website, I send data to the appropriate device through its TCP connection.

I have been able to successfully create a TcpListener in Application_Start and serve connections.  However this doesn't work if IIS has shutdown (or never started) my app pool.

I would like incoming TCP connections on my specific port to start up the app pool and connect to my TcpListener.  Is this possible?

Comment: `TcpListener in Application_Start`, that doesn't seem right. TcpListeners ought to be online all the time. As you noticed, IIS tends to recycle the app pool on idle times. You should run the listeners in a dedicated service.

Comment: I agree.  However if I run the TcpListener in a dedicated service then I will have to go through that service to communicate with the remote devices.  This is possible but it's more work/overhead I'd like to avoid.

Comment: If you want to skip that kind of overhead you'll basically have only one option: keep the app-pool alive. You can tweak some settings in IIS, like shutdown on idle time etc. You can also create a scheduled task which calls a function of your website every 5 minutes. This will keep the app-pool active. But this is a really really really nasty hack.

Comment: An other option, is to let the remote devices wake up your website with an http call. But I think this is really an option since you need tcplisteners in the first place.